# Add FILTER condition if parameter is present

Tags: google-sheets

I have on the top of the page some filtering parameters (see `$H$1` below). They may be left blank, and if so, they should not be used. How to use then conditionally in `FILTER`?? The following don't work:

`FILTER(Contas!G$2:G; 
Contas!$L$2:$L=$G$1;
IF(ISDATE($H$1); Contas!$A$2:$A < $H$1; TRUE())
)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there isn't a date in H1, the IF function will evaluate to a single value (TRUE), and there will be a range mismatch as a result.

You either need to make the first or third argument of the IF a range as well, eg:

`=FILTER(Contas!G$2:G;Contas!$L$2:$L=$G$1;IF(ISDATE($H$1);Contas!$A$2:$A<$H$1;ROW(Contas!$A$2:$A)))`

or you could use the + operator to create an array that essentially says "A2:A is less than H1, OR H1 is blank":

`=FILTER(Contas!G$2:G;Contas!$L$2:$L=$G$1;(Contas!$A$2:$A<$H$1)+ISBLANK($H$1))`